# How to bootstrap sql server express and my database into my custom c# applicaiton

Tags: sql, sql-server, bootstrapping

I am designing a database using sql server express.  Once completed how can I include sql server express and my database into the msi package to automatically install in the client's machine?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520861/how-to-bootstrap-sql-server-2008-express-sp1

Answer (score 2):

You may find life is simpler to go another way - the last time I needed something similar I decided SQLite would do better for me, requiring nothing more than a single DLL to be referenced.

Comment: I've never used SQLite.  Is there a SQLite adapter and could it be used with the ADO.net Entity Framework?

Comment: Don't know, sorry, I've never tried that. The basic .Net component you're looking for is System.Data.SQLite - sqlite.phxsoftware.com

Comment: Lately I've been using SQLCE 4 with the EntityFramework 4.1.  Here is a link for deploying SQLCE http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/06/sql-server-compact-private-deployment.html