# How to Bootstrap SQL Server 2008 Express SP1?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, wix, sql-server-2008-express, bootstrapping

I am trying to bootstrap SQL Server 2008 Express SP1 into my application.  Previously I used Wise for Windows to perform the prerequisite installation, but Wise doesn't support Windows Installer 4.5 yet.

I am now trying to use the Visual Studio 2008 bootstrap technology with WiX 3.0, and have had good success getting the SQL Server prerequisites, and am able to get the manifest for SQL Express 2008 but not SP1.  Also, I need to be able to localize the SQLAccount, but I won't be able to do that through modifying package.xml AFAIK.  In my previous solution, using Wise, I was able to collect the localized string from the target system and pass the parameter directly to the installer command line.

So really, two questions:

1. Where can I find the bootstrap manifest files for SP1 (or can I make them?)
2. How can I localize the SQLAccount since it appears that the command line parameters are decided at compile time with the Visual Studio bootstrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VS 2010 RC or later to bootstrap SQL Express 2008 SP1. WiX 3.5 works there and will allow it.

Answer (score 3):

I only have a maybe solution for yout first question:
[VS.NET 2008 Bootstrapper for SQL Server 2008 Express Edition with Tools](http://youarenotexpectedtounderstandthis.blogspot.com/2009/08/vsnet-2008-prerequisite-for-sql-server.html)

As the title states it also installs the tools and because of that Powershell but hey at least you got sp1.

Comment: It's a start at least.  Actually that link is helpful as it gives a nice example of creating my own bootstrap configuration files.